# Is there a way to duplicate and flip an entire object, armature and it's animations in Blender?

Tags: animation, blender, 3d-modelling

For a project I need character limbs to be separate objects. I have created and rigged a right arm and have created some animations for it but now need to find a way to duplicate and flip the object and all of its animations for a left arm if this is actually possible.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Duplicate object and armature => create empty and parent it to duplicated object => scale the empty by -1 on x axis.